# Mapping a class with a reference property to a class that uses that reference property type as a base class

Tags: c#, automapper

Lets start with some simple example classes.

Here are my source classes, note that CountryDto contains a CurrencyDto reference type property:

```
public class CountryDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CurrencyDto Currency { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencyDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

And here and my destination classes, note that CountryVm inherits CurrencyVm:

```
public class CountryVm : CurrencyVm
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencyVm
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

So lets say I have a `CountryDto` and I wish to map it to a `CountryVm`. My mapping in plain English would be `CountryDto.Name -> CountryVm.Name` and `CountryDto.Currency.Code -> CountryVm.Code`

The question is, what should my automapper configuration look like to achieve this assuming I call the usual:

```
CountryVm myCountryVm = Mapper.Map<CountryDto, CountryVm>(myCountryDto);
```

I'm currently trying this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CountryDto, CountryVm>()
    .IncludeBase<CurrencyDto, CurrencyVm>();

Mapper.CreateMap<CurrencyDto, CurrencyVm>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Code, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Currency.Code));
```

But I get an error saying that it was expecting a type of CurrencyDto but it was CountryDto. What is the correct automapper configuration to achieve this?

Comment: Loss the first mapping and only use the second mapping settings which is working well `Mapper.CreateMap<CurrencyDto, CurrencyVm>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Code, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Currency.Code));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error you're getting is that AutoMapper expects the source and destination type parameters of the `IncludeBase<,>` method to be compatible with the type parameters of the `CreateMap<,>` method, however in your case the `CountryDto` type is completely unrelated to `CurrencyDto`.

If your classes really are as simple as this example then Yacoub's answer shows the simplest way of creating the mapping, however if you want to avoid duplicating the mapping for each derived type you can do it like so:

First map the properties of the destination base type (`CurrencyVm`):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CountryDto, CurrencyVm>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Code, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Currency.Code));
```

Then map the properties of the destination derived type (`CountryVm`) and include the mappings from the base type we added in the above step:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CountryDto, CountryVm>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .IncludeBase<CountryDto, CurrencyVm>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CountryDto, CountryVm>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Code, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Currency.Code));
```